# flyway locations to control dbms changes for multiple DBs

Tags: maven-3, flyway, maven-surefire-plugin

My flyway config - using mvn package to run flyway

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <locations>
                    <location>db.migration.h2</location>
                </locations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I have a maven app that works just fine for one DB  (using h2 database engine) I need to support flyway to other DB systems (db2, oracle ee, postgres.   On another project we are doing something similar flyway config file on flyway version 3.2.1 to manage table cration between H2 and timesten.

(new findings) When I use flyway location  or configuration file entry in hte pom file.  "mvn clean package" works just fine using.  However "mvn verify" gives me the error that it has multiple V#_# files.

I had H2 flyway files in the following directory structure

```
atdd/src/main/java/db/migration/V1_2__comment.java
atdd/src/main/resources/db/migration/V1_1__create_tables.sql
```

I created a subdirectory "h2" under migration and moved the flyway files into that subdirectory.

I made copies db and oracle ee versions of those files in "db/migration/db2" and "db/migration/oracle_ee

RUNNING maven package only gives me:

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found more than one migration with version 1.1
Offenders:
->/Users/XXXXX/Documents/fun/atdd/target/classes/db/migration/h2/V1_1__create_tables.sql (SQL)
->/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/fun/atdd/target/classes/db/migration/db2/V1_1__create_tables.sql (SQL)
```

I have tried using a property file and that does not work either

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>

            <configuration>
                   <configFile>./flyway.properties</configFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

atdd/flyway.properties has

```
 flyway.locations=db.migration.h2
```

Seems to be a problem with what ever runs regression tests (surefire plugin - i am fairly new to maven) 
Is there anything special about surefire plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get working by adding config arguments to failsafe plugin

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <configuration><argLine>-Dflyway.locations=db.migrtion.h2</argLine></configuration>
            <executions>
```

with

```
mvn clean package  verify site -Dflyway.locations=db.migration.h2
```

oddly does not work if I don't have "-Dflyway.locations=db.migration.h2 "

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround, you could try setting location explicitly from your program using `Flyway.setLocations ("some/path/test.sql")`

Answer (score 0):

Flyway searches the entire classpath recursively looking for migrations to apply. The "recursively" word means examining folders nested in other folders.

So all of your SQL files were found. There is no way for Flyway to know which of those nested folders should be used or should be ignored.

As the other Answer suggests, you must specify the desired folders explicitly if you want some oath them ignored.

Comment: yes I want to explicitly list the path.   what I find interesting is that if i move the files from db.migration.db2 and db.migration.h2 to   db.db2 and db.h2 and set the location to db.h2  everytihing works fine.  The latests flyway version always wants to search from db.migration down.  I can't tell it to only search a subdirectory of db.migration.   But my other project is using flyway 2.3.1 and it is limiting it's searches to a specific subdirectory of db.migration.

Comment: @petercooke Please edit your Question with the clarifications in that comment.